# i am not able to select text in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, selenium-webdriver, textselection

```
try {
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(element, 10, 5).clickAndHold()
                .moveByOffset(30, 0).release().perform();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("annotation_save_button")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("transcript_more_options_icon")).click();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am able to select text in Firefox but not so in Chrome. I am not getting an exception while running this piece of code in either browsers.

Comment: i am not able to select text in chrome using above code?

Comment: Well what is the exception?! How can we help if you don't even tell us what the problem is?